# Please help me to solve this problem

Tags: contest-math

Let $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{x}{y}<2$. Find the minimum value $\begin{align*} \frac{x}{2y-x}+\frac{2y}{2x-y} \end{align*}$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is the second question you've asked in the last half hour that shows no work of your own. When you post here you should include in your question what you tried and where you are stuck. You seem to have gotten answers anyway, but often you won't.

Comment: I'm a new member here, and I do not understand the rules here. I apologize for my mistake.

Comment: Can you write the expression you are trying to bound in terms of $z=\frac xy$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x}{2y-x}+\frac{2y}{2x-y}=\frac{x/y}{2-x/y}+\frac{2}{2x/y-1}=\frac{z}{2-z}+\frac{2}{2z-1}$$

where $ \frac{1}{2}<z<2$

Note that $$g(z) = \frac{z}{2-z}+\frac{2}{2z-1}$$ is a function of just one variable $z$

You can find the minimum of $g(z)$ on $ \frac{1}{2}<z<2$ by differentiation.( My answer was $2.8856181$ )

Answer (score 1):

it is $$\frac{x}{2y-x}+\frac{2y}{2x-y}\geq \frac{1}{3}(3+4\sqrt{2})$$
define $$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{2y-x}+\frac{2y}{2x-y}$$ and compute the partial derivatives

Comment: Show your work,please.

Comment: @Yanmath No, *you* show your work please. This isn't a do-my-homework site and you've been given a pretty strong hint.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=\dfrac xy$. Then $$f=\frac{x}{2y-x}+\frac{2y}{2x-y}=\frac{t}{2-t}+\frac2{2t-1}=2\left(\frac{1}{2-t}+\frac1{2t-1}\right)-1$$ Differentiating gives $$\frac{df}{dt}=2\left(\frac1{(2-t)^2}-\frac2{(2t-1)^2}\right)=0$$ for stationary points so $$(2t-1)^2=2(2-t)^2\implies 4t^2-4t+1=2t^2-8t+8\implies 2t^2+4t-7=0$$ Now find the root between $\dfrac12$ and $2$, plug it back into the original expression and prove that its second derivative is greater than $0$ to show that it is a minimum.